# What is the right way to structure my yaml file for my Android app?

Tags: android, yaml

I am starting to put configuration files in my Android application and I found a version of snakeyaml that works for android (if there are better parsers, I am open to anything). The library returns hashmaps of the configuration objects that it reads. I am still fairly new to configuration files so i will just post what I have right now. This works BUT it gives a Hashmap that is 4 layers deep. This seems completely wrong.

```
---
Games:
 Drag Race:
  Avatar:
   classic:
    color:
     - black
     - blue
     - green
     - red
     - yellow
   fastback:
    color:
     - black
     - blue
     - olive
     - red
     - white
   lux:
    color:
     - blue
     - gunmetal
     - orange
     - violet
     - white
   old:
    color:
     - black
     - blue
     - purple
     - red
     - white
 Race to Mars:
  avatar:
   ship:
    - red
    - blue
    - yellow
```

My end goal is to store the following:

- A list of game types
- A list of avatars for each game type
- A list of colors for each avatar

Each list is dependent on the last. My current approach seems very hairy and potentially problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is limited data, so it is difficult to make generalisations, but to me it seems that `ship`, `old` and `classic` are types of avatars so you could make that an attribute next to color:

```
Games:
 Drag Race:
  Avatar:
    type: classic:
    color:
     - black
     - blue
     - green
     - red
     - yellow
    type: fastback
    color:
     - black
     - blue
     - olive
     - red
     - white
    type: lux
    color:
     - blue
     - gunmetal
     - orange
     - violet
     - white
    type: old
    color:
     - black
     - blue
     - purple
     - red
     - white
 Race to Mars:
  avatar:
    type ship:
    color:
     - red
     - blue
     - yellow
```

and lose one level of depth. You can also move the race a type on each avatar:

```
Games:
  - race: drag
    type: classic:
    color:
     - black
     - blue
     - green
     - red
     - yellow
  - race: drag
    type: fastback
    color:
     - black
     - blue
     - olive
     - red
     - white
```

and thereby make the avatar implicit under games (you can of course only do that when there is nothing else in under game but avatars.

The above is based on the general principle that you can exchange attributes of an object with hierarchical groupings of objects within a tree structure and vv.

Comment: I will give these a try tonight. So by your answer, are you implying that it is not terrible to have nested hashmaps when loading configuration files?

Comment: @Shadoninja No it is not, you should have some routines/objects to access the objects (and if necessary write/update them) and make sure only those should know how to access the actual structure. After that it is irrelevant how deep things are nested. See this as as having multiple levels of directories, and not putting everything in the root of your filesystem: Yes you need to know the path to your file, but therefore things that belong together are nicely grouped.

Comment: Ok that is the kind of answer I was looking for. Last night I put together a configuration class than grabs the information from the various levels of the nested hashmaps. The API ended up feeling pretty clean. Thanks.